# Why my POST request doesn't seem to work? (Python requests module)

Tags: python, html, post, python-requests

I am now trying to submit multiple jobs into the web server http://helios.princeton.edu/CONCORD/ using the library requests.

My code looks currently like this:

```
import requests

post_url = "http://helios.princeton.edu/CONCORD"
response_email = "email_example@gmail.com"
sequence_example = "MLGDTMSGGIRGHTHLAIMAVFKMSPGYVLGVFLRKLTSRETALMVIGMAMTTTLSIPHDLMELIDGISLGLILLKIVTQFDNTQVG"
job_description = "example"

info = { "sequence_text": sequence_example, "email_address": response_email, "description": job_description }

r = requests.post(post_url, params=info)
print r.status_code
print r.headers
```

The status returns 200, the headers return as follows, but the server does not submit the job, since I don't get any responses on my email.

```
200
{'content-length': '5637', 'x-powered-by': 'PHP/5.3.2', 'server': 'Apache/2.2.3 (Red Hat)', 'connection': 'close', 'date': 'Mon, 09 Mar 2015 14:14:33 GMT', 'content-type': 'text/html; charset=UTF-8'}
```

Can anybody help me solve this and make it work?

Comment: If the server says that everything is fine and the server then doesn’t do its job, then I guess it’s a server problem.

Comment: @poke: that's because the server received a valid POST, but the body is empty, so there is no actual work to be done..

Comment: The thing that bugs me the most is that manually I can get it done, but when I try optimising it on code I get no response :( If it is in fact a server problem, is there anything I can do about it?

Comment: @ImunoGeek: no, this isn't a server problem. You are posting to the wrong location, and are not sending anything in the POST body.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I don't follow...

Comment: Sorry, I actually got the `action` attribute confused with the `id`. Correcting my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to send *URL query parameters* while the form asks you to send `multipart/form` encoded data:

```html
<form id="query_form" action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Since the form is configured to use `multipart/form-data` you should use either `data` or `files` to POST those parameters:

```
r = requests.post(post_url, files=info)
```

`params` is for *URL parameters*, the part that comes after the `?` in a URL. You can use URL parameters in a POST request *too*, but form data typically is sent as part of the body instead. Using the `files` argument, even with no actual file data, will trigger an encode to `multipart/form-data` here.

Using the http://httpbin.org test server, compare the following responses:

```
>>> import requests
>>> info = {"sequence_text": 'sequence', "email_address": 'email', "description": 'desc'}
>>> print requests.post('http://httpbin.org/post', params=info).text
{
  "args": {
    "description": "desc", 
    "email_address": "email", 
    "sequence_text": "sequence"
  }, 
  "data": "", 
  "files": {}, 
  "form": {}, 
  "headers": {
    "Accept": "*/*", 
    "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate", 
    "Content-Length": "0", 
    "Host": "httpbin.org", 
    "User-Agent": "python-requests/2.5.1 CPython/2.7.9 Darwin/14.3.0"
  }, 
  "json": null, 
  "origin": "81.134.152.4", 
  "url": "http://httpbin.org/post?description=desc&email_address=email&sequence_text=sequence"
}

>>> print requests.post('http://httpbin.org/post', files=info).text
{
  "args": {}, 
  "data": "", 
  "files": {
    "description": "desc", 
    "email_address": "email", 
    "sequence_text": "sequence"
  }, 
  "form": {}, 
  "headers": {
    "Accept": "*/*", 
    "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate", 
    "Content-Length": "411", 
    "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data; boundary=be9a69498ab445b1a79282584877b3bf", 
    "Host": "httpbin.org", 
    "User-Agent": "python-requests/2.5.1 CPython/2.7.9 Darwin/14.3.0"
  }, 
  "json": null, 
  "origin": "81.134.152.4", 
  "url": "http://httpbin.org/post"
}
```

Note the difference in the `url` parameter, as well as the fact that the first request shows parameters parsed into `args` (from the URL), and the other in the `files` parameter (from the POST body, using `multipart/form-data`). Also note the difference in the Content-Type (missing in one) and the Content-Length headers.

Comment: Thank you for the comment, it was helpful, but I am still not getting it to submit the job...

Comment: @ImunoGeek: it could be that the server checks for additional information, such as the `Referrer` header, maybe cookies are set, maybe they use a whitelist of acceptable User-Agent strings, etc. Servers are black boxes, and there is a lot of leeway in the HTTP protocol to vary how a server responds to requests.